# Render HTML returned through AJAX call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am a complete novice in the JavaScript and AJAX stuff. I am trying to make a call to the server using AJAX and display the returned HTML. However instead of rendering the HTML, the browser displays the HTML code. I am not using JQuery and I would prefer not using it (an acute shortage of time and my complete unfamiliarity with JQuery are two major reasons for sticking to basic JavaScript). Is there some way to render the HTML as it is supposed to be using just the basic JavaScript. Here is my code

```
function gotoNext(button){
try {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
}
catch (e) {
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (el) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject ("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (el1) {
            alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX! Please use a compatible browser!!");
        }
    }
}

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        var df = document.getElementById ("dataForm");
        var data = xmlHttp.responseText;
        df.innerText = data;
    }       
};

var id = document.editEnv.id.value;
var sId = document.editEnv.sId.value;
var fileName = document.editEnv.fileName.value;
var group = document.editEnv.group.value;

xmlHttp.open("POST", "newData.jsp", true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
xmlHttp.send ("flag=" + flag + "&id=" + id + "&sId=" + sId + "&fileName=" + fileName + "&group=" + group);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `df.innerHTML = data;`

`innerText` just gets/sets the value as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to replace `innerText` with `innerHTML` The difference lies in the fact that `innerText` doesn't include any HTML tags whereas `innerHTML` does. For example

```
Here is a <a href="what.html">link</a>
```

will display:

```
Here is a link
```

if you call `innerText` on it. However, if you call it with `innerHTML` it will display:

```
Here is a <a href="what.html">link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked! But shouldn't it be the other way round - the first one will be displayed by `innerHTML` and the second one by `innerText`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.innerHTML = data;
```

should work!!
Because using innerHTML will render that html on browser.

innerText will just display HTML code as normal text.